# A way to refresh without manually select text file in excel?

Tags: vba, excel, csv

```
Data > from text > Import text file > ( manually select file )
```

I'm using excel 2010 . In the older version I use to be able to click "refresh' and excel would know which csv to refresh my file without asking to select the file manually.

Is there a way to force excel to know which csv to select when I refresh the data ? ( Workbook connection > refresh > ..) 
instead of excel prompt me back to > Import text file> ( manually .. )

What would be an easier way to do this ? I tried macro .

```
Sub Macro1()

    ActiveWorkbook.Connections("mismatch").Refresh
        With Worksheets("0Mismatch").QueryTables(1)
        .Connection = "TEXT;" & ThisWorkbook.Path & "c:\myfile.csv"
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
     End With
End Sub
```

But it doesn't quite work.

Comment: I thought you can go to `Data > Connections > Refresh All`.  If that is the key you use a lot, you can also add that to the `Quick Access Toolbar`.

Comment: Does the `F9` shortcut also work for data refreshing? (like it does for formulas)

Answer (score 1):

You've made a small mistake when importing file for the first time and you set something like 'Ask text file on refresh' to `True`. You can change it by right click on the data range and go to 'Data range properties'. (I don't use English Excel version so can't provide exact solution).

With VBA you can do it in this way:

```
With Range("A1").QueryTable 'set reference to any single cell where data is

    .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
End With
```

or:

```
With Worksheets("0Mismatch").QueryTables(1)
    .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

With Excel 2010 (English Version), select A1 or a cell that is linked.
Then click on Data tab and then Properties under the Connections section.
An "External Data Range Properties" window will then pop up.
Then uncheck "Prompt for file name on refresh".
This will allow you to have your macro perform a refresh without a file prompt.

Comment: Prompt file name has disappeared for me in the `External Data Range Properties` window. Anyone else seeing this?